# IonInput not allowing to conditionally prevent the onChange event

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic6

On this `StackBlitz` project: https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-hxolmq?file=src%2Fmain.tsx

I have the following custom control...

**/src/controls/IonInputMagic2.js**

```
import { IonInput } from "@ionic/react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const IonInputMagic2 = props => {

  const { value, onChange, validityFunc, ...others } = props
  var isValidValue = validityFunc(value);
  const initialValue = (typeof value !== 'undefined' && isValidValue) ? value : '';
  const [ currentValue, setCurrentValue ] = useState(initialValue);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCurrentValue(initialValue);
  }, [initialValue]);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    var value = e.target.value;
    if (!validityFunc(value)) {
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
    setCurrentValue(value);
    if (onChange) {
      onChange(e);
    }
  };

  return (
    <IonInput value={currentValue} onChange={handleChange} {...others} />
  );
}

export default IonInputMagic2;
```

where you can see I use the `Ionic` control: `IonInput`.

**My problem is:** I have a `validityFunc(...)` that decides if what the user enters is acceptable or not. As per that function, only **numeric and even** digits are allowed. However, the user can enter whatever character with no restrictions.

I have a similar control: `IonInputMagic1` which is very similar, but it uses the `HTML` built-in element: `<input />` instead of the `Ionic` control: `<IonInput />`. On that control the user can only enter what is expected: **only numeric and even digits**.

Here is the difference between those 2 controls (left: works | right: doesn't work)

[image]

Here is how I use both controls:

[image]

**What I need is:** To make `IonInputMagic2` (which uses: `IonInput`) work as: `IonInputMagic1` where the user can only enter numeric and even digits. This is because the `IonInput` uses all the styling and scripting of `Ionic` and I don't want to break all that by using: `<input />`.

Note: I have detected through the DOM that the `IonInput` is a wrapper of: `<input />`.

Any idea on how to achieve that?

If possible, please fork the `StackBlitz` above and post the link here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This change did the trick:

[image]

Here the full code for the component:

```
import { IonInput } from "@ionic/react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const IonInputMagic2 = props => {

  const { value, onChange, validityFunc, ...others } = props
  var isValidValue = validityFunc(value);
  const initialValue = (typeof value !== 'undefined' && isValidValue) ? value : '';
  const [currentValue, setCurrentValue] = useState(initialValue);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCurrentValue(initialValue);
  }, [initialValue]);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    var value = e.target.value;
    if (!validityFunc(value)) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.target.value = currentValue;
      return false;
    }
    setCurrentValue(value);
    if (onChange) {
      onChange(e);
    }
  };

  return (
    <IonInput value={currentValue} onIonInput={handleChange} {...others} />
  );
}

export default IonInputMagic2;
```